# Vuex - getting state after mutation

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I am very new to State Management. I'm currently building a product list with infinite loading features. These are my codes:

This is my component:

```
<template>
  <div class="">
    <section class="space--sm">
      <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div v-for="(data, index) in products" v-bind:key="data.id" class="item col-sm-4 col-xs-12" :id="'data-id-'+data.id" >
                        <a href="#" v-on:click.prevent="selectProduct(data)" >
                            <h4>{{data.name}}</h4>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <infinite-loading force-use-infinite-wrapper="true" @infinite="infiniteHandler" ref="infiniteLoading">
                        <span slot="no-results">
                            No results
                        </span>
                        <span slot="no-more">
                            There are no more results
                        </span>
                    </infinite-loading>
                </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import InfiniteLoading from 'vue-infinite-loading';
import { mapState, mapActions } from 'vuex';
export default {
    name: 'List',
    computed: mapState({
        products: state => state.list.products
    }),
    methods: {
        ...mapActions('list', [
            'selectProduct'
        ]),
        infiniteHandler($state) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.$store.dispatch('products/fetch')

                console.log(this.products.length); 
                //returns 0 but vue debugger says products state got datas

                if (this.products.length) {
                    $state.loaded();
                    if(this.products.length < 15){
                        $state.complete();
                    }
                } else {
                    $state.complete();
                }
            }, 1000);
        },
    },
    components: {
        InfiniteLoading
    }
}
</script>
```

This is my store:

```
import axios from 'axios';

// initial state
const state = {
    products: [],
    selected_product: [],
    page: 1
}

// getters
const getters = {}

// mutations
const mutations = {
    FETCH(state, products) {
        state.products = state.products.concat(products);
    },
    selectProduct (state, { product }) {
        state.selected_product = product;
    },
    updatePage (state) {
        state.page += 1;
    },
}

// actions
const actions = {
    fetch({ commit }) {
        return axios.get('/api/get/products', {
            params: {
                page: state.page
            }
        })
        .then((response) => {
            commit('updatePage')
            commit('FETCH', response.data.data)
        })
        .catch();
    },
    selectProduct ({ state, commit }, product) {
        commit('selectProduct', { product })
    }
}

export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations
}
```

In the infiniteHandler method, I did this :

```
this.$store.dispatch('products/fetch')
```

Afer mutation products state should have loaded data inside (checked using vue debugger) but when I do this after dispatching :-

```
console.log(this.products.length);
```

I get **0** which also means no datas present inside the state. Am I doing anything wrong? Also is this the best practice of using Vuex? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an asynchronous action returns a promise (as yours does), it is returned by the call to `dispatch` so your consumer can wait for the action to complete.

For example

```
async infiniteHandler($state) { // note, this is an "async" function
  setTimeout(() => {
    await this.$store.dispatch('products/fetch') // note the "await"

    console.log(this.products.length); 

    if (this.products.length) {
      $state.loaded();
      if(this.products.length < 15){
        $state.complete();
      }
    } else {
      $state.complete();
    }
  }, 1000);
},
```

---

One more thing, your `catch()` at the end of the *fetch* action won't do you any favours. I'd advise removing it so your consumers can be made aware of any errors. That, or handle the error in your action but still pass the promise rejection on to your component, eg

```
.catch(res => {
  // handle error, maybe with your state
  throw res // make sure to keep rejecting the promise
})
```

and in your component

```
try {
  await this.$store.dispatch('products/fetch') 
  // etc
} catch (e) {
  // do something else
}
```

---

Just noticed another thing... you should use the passed in *context* `state` in your actions, not some global `state` object, ie

```
fetch({ state, commit }) {
```

Comment: Hi Phil, thanks for the good reply.  I'm just wondering if there is any other way to return error to user from action instead of catch(). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`this.$store.dispatch('products/fetch')` is asynchronous. `console.log(this.products.length);` is called before action is finished.

You should use [watch](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) in this case.

```
   watch: {
      products: function (newVal) {
        if (newVal.length) {
          $state.loaded();
          if(newVal.length < 15){
            $state.complete();
          }
        } else {
          $state.complete();
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
async infiniteHandler($state) { 
  setTimeout(() => {
    await this.$store.dispatch('products/fetch') 

    console.log(this.products.length); 

    if (this.products.length) {
      setTimeout(() => {
             $state.loaded();
      }, 1000);
      if(this.products.length < 15){
        $state.complete();
      }
    } else {
      $state.complete();
    }
  }, 1000);
},
```

Comment: Your comment needs some explanation. Answers that are only code are discouraged, and how this bit of code fits into the question is not very clear.